# Mongodb's "mongodump" command, javascript execution error

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

Perhaps I have a complete misunderstanding of how `mongodump` is supposed to work, but I can't seem to get it to do anything besides returning a `JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error.

Here's what I'm doing:

- Mongod is running
- I want to backup a database called "mydb"
- I'm inside the mongo shell
- I tried the command `mongodump --db mydb` and get the above error
- I've tried both `mongodump` and `mongoexport`, both have the same issue

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try the following it will [work](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#usage)

i.Open the terminal

ii. Enter mongodump --collection collectionname --db dbname (Don't go inside mongo shell);

iii.If default port is different(other than 27017) then go for the following command

```
   mongodump --host mongodb1.example.net --port 37017 --username user --password pass    --out /opt/backup/mongodump-2011-10-24
```

Comment: Ah, didn't realise you're meant to do it from outside of mongoDb. Makes sense, got it working!

Comment: You can add the port to the host and use `-o` for output:   
`mongodump --host mongodb1.example.net:37017 -o /opt/backup/mongodump-2011-10-24`

Answer (score 5):

*mongodump,mongorestore is not commands of mongodb shell. It is separate mongodb utlity. You can find it under mongodb bin folder.*

Usually you will need to add all mongodb utilities to the system Path variable and after this easy backup/restore databases from any place in the command line or in the terminal.

Your command looks `mongodump --db mydb` good if your databases in on default port(27017).

Answer (score 3):

I faced the problem in taking mongo dump and I also wanted to store the dump to `S3`. Finally I ended up with a [**bash script**](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/03/bash-script-for-mongodb-backup-to-s3.html) to take mongo dump and store it to S3. I used `mongodump` to take backup.

```
mongodump -h $MONGO_HOST:$MONGO_PORT -d $MONGO_DATABASE
```

Where `$MONGO_HOST`,`$MONGO_PORT` and `$MONGO_DATABASE` are bash variables for `host`, `port` and `database-name` respectively.
You can also use `--username user --password pass` option for `mongodump` command if you have username and password setup on the database. 
[**Here**](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/03/bash-script-for-mongodb-backup-to-s3.html) is the script to take mongodb dump and store it to S3 with a cron.