# mongodb - mongodump is not defined

Tags: mongodb, database-backups, mongodump

I am a newbie to mongodb. I am trying to take a backup of my database using **mongodump**. But whenever I use this command I get the below error

> Referenceerror: mongodump is not defined

I tried creating a new user with all the roles but still I get the same error. Should I add a specific role to take a backup? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you running the `mongodump` command inside mongo shell or in the terminal?

Comment: I tried in both the ways. Still getting the same

Comment: `mongodump` is not a mongo shell command, it is a separate mongodb utlity which usually can be found under mongodb bin folder.

Comment: @chridam Thanks! Then how can I use mongodump?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb's "mongodump" command, javascript execution error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849844/mongodbs-mongodump-command-javascript-execution-error)

Answer (score 14):

'`mongodump`' is a command/tool which is included in the '`mongodb-tools`' package. If you don't have this package installed on your machine, it makes sense that it is not defined. The `mongodb-tools` also provide several other tools used for importing and exporting DBs (like `mongorestore`).

That being said, '`mongodump`' is not a mongo-shell command, you shouldn't be using it in mongo-shell. It's a whole different command that you would be executing just like you execute '`mongod`' or '`mongo`' etc.

Answer (score 4):

- One simple way is to **right-click mongodump.exe and "Run as administrator"**. It will create dump folder in bin of your mongodb home containing all database backups.
- If you want to go with commands, open cmd as administrator and go to bin of your mongodb where you'll be able to fire commands such as mongorestore, mongodump etc. with intended parameters e.g for specific db or interact with remote mongodb.

*tested on (v4.2.3)*

Note: many folks try to execute these commands in mongod where you can execute queries which is wrong, these tools needs to be used separately.

Answer (score 3):

Here ar e 2 simple exemples for a full backup using authentication and without

```
mongodump -h hostname -v -u sys_account -p ys_password --authenticationDatabase admin --out folder_location_for_backup
```

if no authentication

```
mongodump -h hostname -v --out folder_location_for_backup
```

here are the mongorestore commands as well

```
mongorestore -h hostname -v -u admin_user -p admin_password --authenticationDatabase admin --dir folder_location_where_backup_is_located
```

if no authentication

```
mongorestore -h hostname -v  --dir folder_location_where_backup_is_located
```

Answer (score 2):

for windows, you need to start executable file by running following command

> "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongodump.exe" --db your_database_name

Above command will export your database to dump folder. This folder will be located where you have kept your "data" folder. If you use default "data/db" folder then it will be there but if you use different location then it will be kept over there. 
**This command must be run in normal command prompt, not in mongo shell. It is executable not mongo shell command.** Official docs link is [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#bin.mongodump).

Answer (score 0):

Download [MongoDB Command Line Database Tools](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools) .The **mongodump** tool is part of the MongoDB Database Tools package.

Answer (score -1):

There are great chances that `mongodump` is being performed under **Mongo Shell**

`mongodump` should be run directly on command line or terminal (**NOT inside mongo shell**)

For creating dump of database

```
 mongo --db database_name
```

For creating dump of any collection of database

```
mongo --db databas_name --collection collection_name
```